# PCI Parallel port card, cannot get interrupt handler invoked

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt, pci, parallel-port

UPDATE :[ Seemed to have been hardware error, working fine with same code but new card ]

I recently bought a very cheap parallel pci card ([link](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B078Q155K3)) to try to learn a bit about device drivers in linux (via ldd3) on my ubuntu machine

I've connected leds to pins 2-9, and have been able to set/clear the pins using IO ports. However have not been able to raise an interrupt and handle it. Any help or pointers will be appreciated

(please note I have pin 9 directly wired to pin 10)

> lspci

```
07:04.0 Parallel controller: Device 1c00:2170 (rev 0f) (prog-if 01 [BiDir])
Subsystem: Device 1c00:2170
Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: I/O ports at ccf0 [size=8]
Region 1: I/O ports at ccf8 [size=8]
```

after system boot, the io registers are:

```
DATA: 0xff,  STATUS: 0x07, CONTROL: 0xc0
```

I've tried:

```
outb_p(0x10, BASE+2);  // enable irq
outb_p(0x00, BASE);  outb_p(0xFF, BASE); // trigger interrupt
// => DATA: 0xff, STATUS: 0x7b, CONTROL: 0xd0
```

but the interrupt count(as reported by lspci) in **/proc/stat** 's intr line for IRQ11 (as reported by lspci ) remains zero

I have also tried wrapping the above seq between `probe_irq_on/off()` (with an additional outb_p(0x00, BASE+2); udelay(5) in between) which also fails to spot and report any interrupt.
This kernel probing was done after a call to `pci_enable_device(dev)` in the module code.

Please let me know if any other info is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the problem is unrelated to your software. The port probably generates interrupts based on handshake signals from the connected device—e.g. data received/data available. (I don’t remember the details.) Since you only have LEDs connected, and not a device, the parallel port never sees the conditions(s) that can cause an interrupt.

Comment: thanks pri. From what I've read the PC Parallel port states that once interrupts have been enabled, a low-to-high edge on pin 10 raises an interrupt. I assumed it should be same for my setup (a pci parallel card) but am not sure, any pointers to links that will help me figure out would be wonderful

Comment: Ok, sorry, I guess my suspicion was wrong.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you are not reading the existing driver code and see how it's done. Btw, interrupt countes are in */proc/interrupts*.

Comment: Changed the card with another, and everything working as expected. Appreciate the responses